# AWS Lambda callback on asynchronous execution

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have lambda function which I invoke in a loop (boto3) asynchronous.

```
for obj in somelist:
    aws_lambda.invoke(FunctionName='lambda_name', 
                    InvocationType='Event', 
                    LogType='Tail',
                    Payload=bytes(obj))
```

It takes few seconds to process and I would like it to report back to my application.

How do I do that? I could send SNS message from lambda, there is also CloudWatch but it feels like there should be an easier way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want your application to stop, SNS is really your best option. That, or emulating the basic feature of SNS by passing the functions an endpoint to call when they're done. Otherwise your options boil down to more or less logging state somewhere and polling for updates or executing a synchronous call in another thread.

Comment: I've been looking at it yesterday and seems like SNS is the best option.

Comment: so invoke_async is not asynchronous? *and* you can't callback on the result?! That's crazy.